# cocos2d Tinting sprite white with opacity

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to figure out how to put a tint layer ontop of my sprite. I want to make the sprite have a white layer tint with  50% opacity.

I am doing

```
[mySprite setColor:ccc3(255,255,255)];
[mySprite setOpacity: 128];
```

But what I get is a non-tinted sprite, but my layer that's just slightly transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, `setColor` works best on already white sprites, for other colored sprites, the color applied gets multiplied. So if you multiply any other color with white, you'll still get only that same color.

You might want to use other blend modes to achieve what you need or just use a white sprite. To set a blend mode, you have to use the function `setBlendFunc` before/after calling `setColor`.